# Set a screensaver as wallpaper in Unity?

Tags: xscreensaver

Is this possible on Ubuntu desktop 12.04? Specifically, I would like to run xscreensaver as the Unity desktop wallpaper.

Comment: do you want/mean to use **live wallpaper** instead of normal wallppr?

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and paste these following commands

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-tools
gconftool-2 -type bool -set /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop false /usr/lib/xscreensaver/glmatrix -root
```

Then restart to apply the changes.

credit goes to [Life hacker](http://lifehacker.com/299410/use-a-screensaver-as-desktop-wallpaper)

Comment: I can't get this to work. Also, "show_desktop" doesn't show an option in gconf-editor.